# Get count of items whilst selecting from the same table and then sorting by the count column

Tags: mysql

Say for example, I have a table that looks like this

```
ID  NAME            YREF    UREF
1   ADAM BLAISE     0001    0007
2   JAMES HARDY     0002    0005
3   PHILIP HENRY    0003    0002
4   PETER SCHWARTZ  0004    0001
5   WILL MADISON    0005    0002
6   JEREMY PINOT    0006    0002
7   JOHN WILLIARD   0007    0007
8   MARK WILLIARD   0008    0005
9   JOHN VAUGHN     0009    0002
10  DAVID JAMES     0010    0002
```

I want to be able to get a count for each row how many times each user sent their `YREF` to another user so that the said user referenced it when submitting their own names, so that a table that looks like this can be got:

```
ID  NAME            YREF    COUNT (i.e. how many times their YREF appeared in the UREF column of other users)
1   ADAM BLAISE     0001    1
2   JAMES HARDY     0002    5
3   PHILIP HENRY    0003    0
4   PETER SCHWARTZ  0004    0
5   WILL MADISON    0005    2
6   JEREMY PINOT    0006    0
7   JOHN WILLIARD   0007    2
8   MARK WILLIARD   0008    0
9   JOHN VAUGHN     0009    0
10  DAVID JAMES     0010    0
```

Comment: Generate a set of data which contains the counts and join it back to your best set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t1.yref, coalesce(t2.cnt, 0) as count
from your_table t1
left join 
(
  select uref, count(*) as cnt
  from your_table
  group by uref
) t2 on t1.yref = t2.uref
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate a set of data with counts and join it back to the base set.  other database engines would allow windowed sets using `OVER` syntax, but mySQL doesn't support these.

```
SELECT A.ID, A.Name, A.YREF, coalesce(B.MyCount,0)
FROM tableName A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT count(*) myCount, UREF 
            FROM tableName 
            GROUP BY UREF) B
 on A.YREF = B.UREF
```

Comment: `inner join` eliminates records where the  count is zero

Comment: This is true.  Initially I was joining on ID, and forgot to update syntax to accomidate